# Copying of an array of objects to another Array without object reference in javascript(Deep copy)

Tags: javascript

I have a scenario where i need to copy the array of Objects(Main array) to another Temp array which should not have object reference basically if i make any modification to  Main array it should not reflect in the Temp array so that i will preserve the copy independently.

I have used one of the code snippet from stack overflow this one does partially like if i delete all objects from the Main array the temp array still hold the value but when i do some modifications in main array and click cancel button iam removing all objects from the main array using array.Removeall(); but the modification still exist in Temp array so which means that object having a reference.

```
clone: function (existingArray) {
  var newObj = (existingArray instanceof Array) ? [] : {};
  console.debug('newObj value is ' + newObj);
  for (i in existingArray) {
    console.debug('i value is' + i);
    if (i == 'clone') continue;
    console.debug('existingArray[i] value ' + existingArray[i]);
    if (existingArray[i] && typeof existingArray[i] == "object") {

      newObj[i] = this.clone(existingArray[i]);
    } else {
      console.debug('in else part ' + existingArray[i]);
      newObj[i] = existingArray[i];
    }
  }
  return newObj;
}
```

my object structure is like

iam using knockout framework.

```
newObjectCreation = function (localIp, RemoteIp, areaId) {
  this.localIP = ko.observable(localIp);
  this.remoteIP = ko.observable(RemoteIp);
  this.areaId = ko.observable(areaId);
};

template.ProtocolArray.push(new newObjectCreation('', '', '')); // to create default row
```

Comment: Do the objects contain anything which is not expressible as [JSON](http://json.org/) (not object literal)? If not, you could simple do: `var clone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(src));`

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copying array by value in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486085/copying-array-by-value-in-javascript)

Answer (score 138, accepted):

Let me understand: you don't want just have a new array, but you want to create a new instance for all objects are present in the array itself? So if you modify one of the objects in the temp array, that changes is not propagated to the main array?

If it's the case, it depends by the values you're keeping in the main array. If these objects are simple objects, and they can be serialized in JSON, then the quickest way is:

```
var tempArray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(mainArray));
```

If you have more complex objects (like instances created by some your own constructors, html nodes, etc) then you need an approach ad hoc.

Edit:

If you don't have any methods on your `newObjectCreation`, you could use `JSON`, however the constructor won't be the same. Otherwise you have to do the copy manually:

```
var tempArray = [];
for (var i = 0, item; item = mainArray[i++];) {
    tempArray[i] = new newObjectCreation(item.localIP, item.remoteIP, item.areaId);
}
```

Comment: so will var tempArray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(mainArray)); do a deep copy i.e without object reference? 2.)regarding that manual copying doesnt this manual copying still point to same object reference.

Comment: if you have only properties and not methods, and you don't care about having exactly the same object with the same constructor, but just have plain object that have the same values, yes, you will have a sort of "deep copy". To make it clears: `function foo(a) { this.a = a }; var main = [new foo(1)], temp = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(main));` then you will have `main[0].a` equals to `1` and `temp[0].a` as well. If you change the last one `temp[0].a = 4` that changes won't be reflected to `main[0].a`. However `main[0].constructor` is `foo` and `temp[0].constructor` is `Object`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that answer I appreciate your help template.Temparray(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(ko.toJS(template.Mainarray()))));   I have used above snippet and it works as expected with n=knockout framework.Kudos to u :)

Comment: Why doesn't JavaScript have a function to do this? Like `function cloneObject (o) { return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(o)); }` ...except doing something faster behind-the-scenes. Or even better: a method for all objects called `clone()` so you could just do `mainArray.clone()`.

Comment: Thank you @ZER0! Using the native JSON functions is the most elegant suggestion to do this that I have seen.

Answer (score 37):

For some other people with the same question. You could also do it this way.
Using the new [es6 features](http://es6-features.org) you could create a copy of an array (without reference) and a copy of every object without one level of references.

```
const copy = array.map(object => ({ ...object }))
```

It's much more functional and idiomatic IMHO

> Note: **Spread syntax effectively goes one level deep** while copying an array. Therefore, it may be unsuitable for copying multidimensional arrays as the following example shows (**it's the same with Object.assign() and spread syntax**).
>   More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

So basically if your objects doesn't have objects as properties. This syntax is everything you need. Unfortunately there is not "out of the box" deep clone feature on the spec but you can always use a library if that's what you need

**Browser Compatibility Warning:** I think it is part of the specification of Ecma now, but some browsers doesn't have full [support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Browser_compatibility) of spread syntax jet. But using one of the popular transpilers out there you will be fine

Comment: saved many hours of work

Comment: Do you know if this way is faster than using the `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(mainArray));` ?

Comment: @Vitomir this solution is way more valid those days. `parse + stringify` is 'old-school'

Answer (score 24):

Lodash can be used for deep copying objects [_.cloneDeep(value)](https://lodash.com/docs#cloneDeep)

```
var objects = [{ 'a': 1 }, { 'b': 2 }];

var deep = _.cloneDeep(objects);
console.log(deep[0] === objects[0]);
// → false
```

Answer (score 19):

To copy the values of an array without copying the reference of the array, you can simply do:

```
const tempArray = [...mainArray];
```

This is the recommended solution for AirBnb's JS Style Guide: https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#arrays

However, this will not create new referenes for the objects inside the array. To create a new reference for the array and the objects inside, you can do:

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(mainArray));
```

Comment: Arrays are without reference but the object inside is.

Comment: For an array of arrays, try this: `var start = [[4,2,6,5],[1,8,7,3]];
var temp = start.map(e => e.slice(0));
var tempEs6 = start.map(e => [...e]);`

Answer (score 10):

So you want a deep copy without object reference? Sure, use [`.slice()`](http://javascript.info/tutorial/array#method-slice).

Example:

```
var mainArr = [],
    tmpArr = []

tmpArr = mainArr.slice(0) // Shallow copy, no reference used.
```

PS: I don't think double-JSON parsing is [performance wise](http://jsperf.com/double-json-vs-slice).

Comment: This did not work for me under Google Chrome 25. After I modified the new array's first object it also modified the original array's first object. No downvote though as it does work with simple arrays, just not with arrays of objects which I think is the OP's point.

Comment: This didnt work for me either. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28482593/copying-an-array-of-objects-into-another-array-in-javascript-deep-copy

Comment: But double-JSON parsing works...
According to MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):
"For object references (and not the actual object), slice copies object references into the new array. Both the original and new array refer to the same object. If a referenced object changes, the changes are visible to both the new and original arrays."

Comment: This won't work if the array has objects in it. It will copy the object references.

Comment: As everyone said. This simply does not work unless you have simple objects in the array. This won't work when using most Js frameworks in most cases (this is an oversimplification). This answer does not answer the question.

Comment: This won't work if you have object type {} in your array

Comment: This also doesn't work if you have an **array of arrays** like `[[4,2,6,5],[1,8,7,3]]`. In this case, you can do the following: `var start = [[4,2,6,5],[1,8,7,3]]; var temp = start.map(e => e.slice(0))`

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Angular's copy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy): `angular.copy();`

Answer (score 1):

On nested array you can do:

```
    const origin = [{ cat: 'Bengal', dog: 'Birman' }, { cat: 'Abyssinian', dog: 'Bombay' }];
    const clone = [];
    origin.forEach(v=> clone.push(Object.assign({}, v)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this function
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone

```
let deepClonedArrayOfObjects = structuredClone(originalArrayOfObjects);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `angular.copy`. But not for the whole array (because it would pass array items by reference), but iterate it and use `angular.copy` on its members.

```
var newArray = [];
for (var i = 0, item; item = mainArray[i];) {
    newArray[i] = angular.copy(item);
    i++;
}
```