# Deep copying array of nested objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, deep-copy

I am trying to deep copy array of nested objects in javascript. My array look like this

```
var arr = [{name:"adam",age:"21"},
    {name:"freddie",age:"35",children:[{name:"mercury",age:"25"}]},
    {name:"jim",age:"35",children:[{name:"morrison",age:"25",children:[{name:"some", age:"40"}]}]}
    ];
```

I want to make a deep copy of every object inside the array that is i want to create a exact copy of arr into new array which should not have object reference. Depth of array is also unknown that is children array can be upto any level.
I have gone through this link
[Copying of an array of objects to another Array without object reference in javascript(Deep copy)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9885821/copying-of-an-array-of-objects-to-another-array-without-object-reference-in-java) but that did not help me. I googled and found some solutions in jQuery but that did not help me as i dont have knowledge of jQuery.

I also tried implementing it with recursion but that's not working too 
http://ideone.com/kJi5X3

I want to do it in javascript only without using jQuery or anything. I am new to JavaScript so i may have missed if there is any library or simple method to do this.
Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You linked to a question that this could have been closed as a duplicate of and said it didn't help - can you clarify _why_ it didn't help, so we understand why this isn't a duplicate of that one?

Comment: Also note that jQuery is _just a javascript library_, if there was a jQuery solution, are you ruling out that library while another one would be acceptable?

Comment: @James Thorpe - No i am wondering if there is any way to do it with recursion or any other logic i dont have knowledge of jQuery and i want to do this ASAP.

Comment: @James That link did not help me because it was not working for nested objects.

Comment: Regarding that potential duplicate - please read beyond the top voted accepted answer - indeed note that that answer itself points you to one of the others.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You have two main options:

1. Use `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse`:

   ```
    var copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(original));
   ```

**But** I've never liked that. A round-trip through text is inefficient at best, and it won't handle functions or `Date`, `RegExp`, `undefined`, etc. values correctly unless you write a replacer and a reviver.

2. Use a recursive function, something like this:

```js
var toString = Object.prototype.toString;
function deepCopy(obj) {
    var rv;

    switch (typeof obj) {
        case "object":
            if (obj === null) {
                // null => null
                rv = null;
            } else {
                switch (toString.call(obj)) {
                    case "[object Array]":
                        // It's an array, create a new array with
                        // deep copies of the entries
                        rv = obj.map(deepCopy);
                        break;
                    case "[object Date]":
                        // Clone the date
                        rv = new Date(obj);
                        break;
                    case "[object RegExp]":
                        // Clone the RegExp
                        rv = new RegExp(obj);
                        break;
                    // ...probably a few others
                    default:
                        // Some other kind of object, deep-copy its
                        // properties into a new object
                        rv = Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(prev, key) {
                            prev[key] = deepCopy(obj[key]);
                            return prev;
                        }, {});
                        break;
                }
            }
            break;
        default:
            // It's a primitive, copy via assignment
            rv = obj;
            break;
    }
    return rv;
}
var a = [1, {foo: "bar"}, ['a', 'b'], new Date()];
snippet.log(JSON.stringify(a));
var b = deepCopy(a);
snippet.log(JSON.stringify(b));
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Note that the above uses ES5 features present on all modern browsers but not some older ones, like IE8. All of the features used above can be polyfilled, however, for older browsers.

That doesn't try to get into handling custom constructor functions or preserving prototypes on objects in the array; doing so makes things **dramatically** more complicated and impossible to make perfect without a convention for how to call those constructors for a copy operation. You can get close by assigning the same prototype, but that wouldn't account for logic within the constructor function and in particular for functions set up as closures within it.

Comment: Crowder that worked flawlessly, Thank you very much :)

Comment: This is the only correct way to do it. The spread operator ( `...object`) and `Oject.assign` solution which  are often mentioned on the internet are only working for "top level" values. Child objects which are nested inside the original object are referenced when using the spread operator or `Object.assign` function. This means if the child object values are changing, they are changing in all copies as well.